# Hide the tabbar when keyboard display

Tags: android, keyboard

I got one problem, when i type in editbox the keyboard pop up right.I need that the edit text box should view above of the keyboard.

i have added this in manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

and what i am getting is

[image]

and this is what i need

[image]

could anybody help me out to hide the tabbar only @Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that.... add the following inside the activity tag of your application manifest.

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your Manifest.xml,  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"`

Comment: @priya: your UI holding Scrollview?

Comment: i didn't get UI holding Scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of disabling auto suggestion which pops out while typing your words.. In some case, you dont require it..

So try this,,
in your .xml file for `EditText`

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

or you can try out programatically like this...

```
editfield.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.RL_main_review);
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                            .getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its
                                            // probably a keyboard...
                        tl_tab.setVisibility(TableLayout.GONE);

                    } else {
                        tl_tab.setVisibility(TableLayout.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
```